# Syntax for Unicode characters in regexes in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex, unicode

What's the syntax to use for general Unicode characters in regular expressions in Google Sheets?

Use case: When using `REGEXREPLACE` with user submitted strings in Google Sheets, I have come across a special Unicode white-space character ([No-break space](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en), hex 0xA0 or dec 160) that resisted my efforts to be matched by the standard white-space character class `\s`.

> Google products use RE2 for regular expressions. Google Sheets supports RE2 except Unicode character class matching. Learn more on [how to use RE2 expressions](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt). [Source](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)

The reference is quite dense and a bit confusing, I haven't managed to make it work yet using it.

Comment: Welcome. Questions on this site that include a brief description of the search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask] usually are well received by this community. On questions about spreadsheet formulas it is recommended to include sample input/output as well the formulas what you already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways of matching Unicode characters according to [Google Sheets' regular expression documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax):

- Using exactly two digit hex code: `\xA0`
- Using up to three digits octal code: `\240`
- Using any length of hex: `\x{A0}` or `\x{0A0}` or `\x{0000000A0}` etc. (any reasonable number of leading 0's is allowed apparently)

Other ways of specifying characters that belong to RE2 are sadly **not** supported by Google Sheets, e.g. `\%d160`

Comment: how about character ranges?