# How do I replace a paragraph break (i.e. Enter) with a Shift+Enter character in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, regex

Edit 2023-06:  I just did some testing and the issue is that *replacement* characters (the bottom input box) are taken literally, even when the regex option is check-marked. Regex for characters to be replaced (the top input box) works fine.

That is, what regexes do I place in these two boxes
[image]

I have read [Syntax for Unicode characters in regexes in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134784/syntax-for-unicode-characters-in-regexes-in-google-sheets) to no avail.

I found from one answer that `[\n]` matches paragraph mark.  Now all I need is the character for Shift+Enter.

Comment: The recent edit should be rolled back as it's a different issue. It's worth mentioning that Regex never worked on the "Replace with" box. Also, it's worth mentioning that this question was answered three years ago, but just that answer just got an unvote in May.

Comment: @Wicket It's the same issue.  I asked how I can replace a character with another one.  The answer, which I explained in the edit, is that it is not possible.

Comment: Edits should not invalidate already posted answers.

Comment: Well, since the edit is simply an explanation (and answer) of the original question it could not have changed the validity of already-posted answers.

Answer (score 3):

The "shift-enter" character in Google Docs is called "vertical tab".

| Dec | Hex | Binary | HTML | Char | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 09 | 00001001 | &#9; | HT | Horizontal Tab |
| 10 | 0A | 00001010 | &#10; | LF | Line Feed |
| **11** | **0B** | **00001011** | **&#11;** | **VT** | **Vertical Tab** |
| 12 | 0C | 00001100 | &#12; | FF | Form Feed |

Thus, on regex search/replace, you can \v or \x0B to represent the shift-enter (Vertical Tab).

Note:
Line Feed is the normal enter, represented there as a paragraph mark.
Form Feed is the forced page break.

Comment: I just did some testing and the issue is that the _replacement_ character is taken literally, even when the regex option is check-marked.  Regex for the character to be replaced works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[^\S\n\t ]`

[image]

- `\S` matches any non-white character
- `\n` matches a paragraph mark
- `\t` matches a tab
- matches a white space
- `[^]` means not so `[^\S\n\t ]` matches any character that is not non-white character, is not a paragraph mark, is not a tab character and is not any a blank space.

Reference

- [Search and use find and replace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754#regular_expressions)

Answer (score -2):

I think what you are looking for is `CHAR(10)`

As an example:

```
=Join(CHAR(10),"Line", "New line")
```

[image: CHAR(10) new line]

Comment: I'm looking for the regexes for replacement in Google _Docs_.